# Edge Extension, packaging: The site URL is not a valid URL

Tags: microsoft-edge, manifoldjs

I am trying to package my Edge extension using the tutorial here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/extensions/guides/packaging/using-manifoldjs-to-package-extensions

I have created the extension (ported from Chrome) and tested it by loading it in Edge. It works great. Now I want to package it.

I run

```
manifoldjs -l debug -p edgeextension -f edgeextension -m path\manifest.json
```

and get the error:

```
[error] manifoldjs  : The site URL is not a valid URL.
```

I don't know what it is referring to. I get the same error if content_script.js is blank. This is my manifest file:

```
{
    "author": "My name",
    "name": "My name",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "background": {
        "page": "background.html",
        "persistent": true
    },
    "browser_specific_settings": {
        "edge": {
            "browser_action_next_to_addressbar": true
        }
    },
    "browser_action": {
        "default_title": "My name",
        "default_icon": {
            "20": "icon_20.png",
            "25": "icon_25.png",
            "30": "icon_30.png",
            "40": "icon_40.png"
        }
    },
    "content_security_policy": "default-src 'none'; script-src 'self'",
    "icons": {
        "48": "icon48.png",
        "128": "icon128.png"
    },
    "permissions": [
      "*://*/*"
    ],
    "-ms-preload": {
        "backgroundScript": "backgroundScriptsAPIBridge.js",
        "contentScript": "contentScriptsAPIBridge.js"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems you have to define the correct path to manifest.json

```
manifoldjs -l debug -p edgeextension -f edgeextension -m [changeThisToYourPath]/manifest.json
```